# How to set the value of an enumeration?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, enumeration

I have a problem setting the value od an enumeration.

In my code I define this enumeration:

```
    public enum PartType
    {
        Application,
        Operating_System,
        Hardware
    }

    public PartType Part { get; set; }
```

Then, in the same class I try to set a value of this eumeration in this way (how I have read on the C# documentation):

```
   if (row["part"] == "a")
   {
        Part.Application;
   }
```

But it signed as error. Why? What am I missing? How can I solve?

Comment: `Part = PartType.Application;`

Comment: How would you do it if it was a string and not an enum?

Comment: _"How can I solve?"_ - by pasting the error in your favorite web search engine, reading why other people got the same error, understanding what is going wrong and correcting it with what you actually want that code to do.

Answer (score 3):

It should be :

`Part = PartType.Application;`